# How to add numbers to bars with D3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've created a chart and it works fine, but I can't find out how to add numbers to columns. Numbers appear only if I hover the columns.
Tried different variants:

```
svg.selectAll("text").
data(data).
enter().
append("svg:text").
attr("x", function(datum, index) { return x(index) + barWidth; }).
attr("y", function(datum) { return height - y(datum.days); }).
attr("dx", -barWidth/2).
attr("dy", "1.2em").
attr("text-anchor", "middle").
text(function(datum) { return datum.days;}).
attr("fill", "white");
```

A link to my example: https://jsfiddle.net/rinatoptimus/db98bzyk/5/

Comment: Looked through several tutorials: http://cagrimmett.com/til/2016/04/26/responsive-d3-bar-chart.html, http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/making-a-bar-chart

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternate idea to @gerardofurtado is to instead of a `rect` append a `g`, then group the text and rect together.  This prevents the need for double-data binding.

```
var bars = svg.selectAll(".bar")
  .data(newData)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "bar")
  // this might be affected:
  .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
    return "translate(" + i * barWidth + ",0)";
  });

bars.append("rect")
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return y(d.days);
  })
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return height - y(d.days) + 1;
  })
  .style({
    fill: randomColor
  }) // color  bars
  .attr("width", barWidth - 1)
  .on('mouseover', tip.show)
  .on('mouseout', tip.hide);

bars.append("text")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.days;
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return y(d.days);
  })
  .attr("x", barWidth / 2)
  .style("text-anchor", "middle");
```

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/db98bzyk/8/).

Comment: Thank you, Mark! Unfortunately I can't accept both answers as correct variants, but your answer is very useful!

Comment: @user3601990 accept Mark's answer. It's the best one. I didn't wrote it using groups because I was too lazy, but this is the best way, it uses less code and gives you more flexibility.

Comment: Mark, how to correct this: if toggle radio btns columns move away?

Comment: @user3601990: fixed here: https://jsfiddle.net/db98bzyk/8/, I changed the selector to be by `class` and I didn't update the transition.

Answer (score 2):

When you do this:

```
svg.selectAll("text")
```

you are selecting text elements that already exist in your SVG. In an enter selection, it's important selecting something that *doesn't exist*:

```
svg.selectAll(".text")
    .data(newData)
    .enter()
    .append("svg:text")
    .attr("x", function(datum) {
        return x(datum.name) + x.rangeBand()/2
    })
    .attr("y", function(datum) {
        return y(datum.days) - 10;
    })
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function(datum) {
        return datum.days;
    })
    .attr("fill", "white");
```

Here is your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c210osht/

Comment: Stackoverflow needs a way to set a flag about whose already in the process of answering a question, that way you and I won't keep doing this :)

Comment: @Mark indeed, let's propose that on "Meta"... they will implement it [in 6 to 8 weeks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514)

Comment: Oh, if I choose "Сортировать" (sort) bars are moving to the right)

Comment: @user3601990 that's **another** problem. Please post another question.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the [d3fc bar series component](https://d3fc.io/api/series-api.html#bar), which allows you to add data-labels via the [decorate pattern](https://d3fc.io/introduction/decorate-pattern.html).

Here's what the code would look like:

```
var svgBar = fc.seriesSvgBar()
    .xScale(xScale)
    .yScale(yScale)
    .crossValue(function(_, i) { return i; })
    .mainValue(function(d) { return d; })
    .decorate(function(selection) {
      selection.enter()
        .append("text")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0, -10)")
        .text(function(d) { return d3.format(".2f")(d); })
        .attr("fill", "black");
    });
```

Here's a [codepen with the complete example](https://codepen.io/ColinEberhardt/pen/oYrZZv).

**Disclosure**: I am a core contributor to the d3fc project!